# Exit from for loop when any jQuery Deferred fails

Tags: jquery-deferred

In the below code, whenever any one of the deferred object fails I need to quit the for loop. Whenever the loop upper-case `red` or `yellow` color it fails and I want to avoid other deferreds getting executed.

```
var colours = ['violet', 'indigo', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'orange', 'red'];

var capitalize = function(text) {
  var deferred = $.Deferred(),
    delay = (1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 5)) * 500;

  setTimeout(function() {
    if (text === 'red' || text === 'yellow') {
      deferred.reject('error colour', true);
    } else {
      deferred.resolve(text.toUpperCase());
    }
  }, delay);

  return deferred.promise();
}

var deferreds = [],
  result = [];

for (var i = 0; i < colours.length; i++) {
  var deferred = capitalize(colours[i]);

  deferred.done(function(t) {
    console.log(t);
    result.push(t);
  }).fail(function(e) {
    console.log(e);
  });

  deferreds.push(deferred);
}

$.when.apply($, deferreds).done(function(){
    console.log(result);
}).fail(function(e){
    console.log(e);
});
```

[Link to jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abjb0ogf/1/)

**EDIT:**

I'm building a cordova based mobile application with backbone. I've to use localStorage for persistence and I've to encrypt all the data before persisting. Though storing/retrieving data with localstorage is synchronous, to encrypt/decrypt the data I've to call the native device API which is asynchronous. I thought of using the [Backbone.localstorage](https://github.com/jeromegn/Backbone.localStorage/blob/master/backbone.localStorage.js) plugin but it is not developed for async... so not much useful!

I'm developing my own plugin based on that. I've nearly completed most of the code except one method i.e. `findAll`.

The `findAll` method returns all the models that are stored in localstorage.

```
// exiting method in the Backbone.Localstorage plugin
extend(Backbone.LocalStorage.prototype, {
  // ...
  findAll: function() {
    var result = [];
    for (var i = 0, id, data; i < this.records.length; i++) {
      id = this.records[i];
      data = this.serializer.deserialize(this.localStorage().getItem(this._itemName(id)));
      if (data != null) result.push(data);
    }
    return result;
  }
});
```

In localstorage all the models are encrypted and stored as string. I've to decrypt them before deserializing back to models. The `this.crypto` class decrypt the string returned from localstorage and deserialize back to model. The encryption/decryption is aysnc and so it returns a promise.

```
// Method in my new plugin
findAll: function () {
  var deferred = $.Deferred(),
    deferreds = [],
    result = [], 
    errors = [];

  // this.records contains all the model ids
  for (var i = 0, id, data; i < this.records.length; i++) {
    id = this.records[i];

    // this.crypto return a promise with the backbone model as parameter
    var d = this.crypto.deserialize(this.localStorage().getItem(this._itemName(id)));

    d.done(function(model) {
      // I've to maintain the order in result so storing the index
      result.push({ index: i, model: model });
    }).fail(function(error) {
      errors.push(error);
    });

    deferreds.push(d);
  }

  $.when.apply($, deferreds)
    .done(function() {
      // TODO: sort the result based on i and resolve it
      deferred.resolve(sortedResult);
    })
    .fail(...);

  return deferred.promise();
}
```

There are chances an error can occur while decrypting and in that case I've to stop the complete process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your new `findAll` method will simplify as follows :

```
findAll: function () {
    var promises = this.records.map(function(record) {
        return this.crypto.deserialize(this.localStorage().getItem(this._itemName(record)));
    });
    return $.when.apply(null, promises).then(function() {
        return Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments);//convert arguments to array
    });
}
```

On success this will return a promise of an array of results in the order you want - no need to sort anything. Any individual async failure will cause the returned promise to be rejected. However, that rejection will be too late to prevent other async calls, which were already made.

In order to allow a failure to inhibit further calls of `this.crypto.deserialize(...)`, you have to perform the calls serially (in a daisy chain), thus allowing the outcome of each call to determine the next course of action.

```
findAll: function () {
    var results = [];
    return this.records.reduce(function(promise, record) {
        return promise.then(function(result) {
            if(result) results.push(result);
            return this.crypto.deserialize(this.localStorage().getItem(this._itemName(record)));
        });
    }, $.when()).then(function() {
        return results;
    });
}
```

As before, on success this will return a promise of an array of results in the order you want.

As each stage is executed only if the previous stage was successful, inhibition of further calls will happen automatically on async failure. Although `.reduce(...)` built a then chain unconditionally, a rejection will force the chain down its fail path - thens to the right of the failure will be skipped (they have no fail handlers).

Things are slightly different if you need to force a failure based on testing `result`, but the overall pattern is essentially the same.

Comment: I'm getting **undefined is not a function** error in this line `return Array.prototype.apply(arguments)` I think it should be `Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)` right?

Comment: Yes, precisely so, I forget .slice`. Well spotted.

Comment: One more question, is it slice.call or slice.apply?

Comment: Either will do the job. The two methods are very similar, and actually identical if only one parameter is passed.

Answer (score 1):

> *"whenever ... it fails and I want to avoid other deferreds getting executed"*

Think about that for a moment. This is impossible.

- You have a `for` loop that creates and runs asynchronous functions (i.e. "deferreds").
- The loop finishes *long* before even the first of these functions returns (i.e. "resolves").
- When the first of these functions returns with a negative result (i.e. "the promise is rejected"), what could you possibly do at this point to prevent the others from executing? It's already too late for that.

There are several possibles solutions, but they all depend on a much better problem definition.

Comment: So.. in this case, executing the deferreds one by one (sequentially) is a good choice?

Comment: Not necessarily. I mean, if you *don't* want asynchronous behavior, why bother with deferreds in the first place? However, if you *do* want asynchronous behavior... As I said, your problem definition/description is lacking. Explain what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I've tried to explain the real context in the question. Hope it'll help you understand.

Comment: Yes, that's certainly useful. Can you say why you want to stop the process at the first error (instead of simply waiting for all async calls to return and examining the overall result)? I mean, other than "it would waste CPU cycles on the client", because these cycles would be spent in any case in the normal operation of your page, by not spending them in case of an error you really do not gain any mentionable benefit.

Comment: Let's say I've 100 items in the backbone collection and due to some rare reasons the crypto plugin failed while deserializing one model and I don't want the user to wait till the remaining 99 items got deserialized finally to say the user "Something went wrong. Please try again". Is this make sense?

Comment: Yes. But how does your UI work in this case? Do you have multiple sections on the screen that resolve individually, as soon as their respective data gets decrypted/deserialized? Or does your user have to sit tight while the whole thing resolves in a monolithic way? Because if they have to sit tight in the "no error" (i.e. the most probable) case, what do you gain by making the error ("improbable") case faster? OTOH, if the screen updates section-by-section, you could display errors section-by-section, letting each function call finish on its own.

Comment: If we are talking about the monolithic case, then you gain nothing by asynchronicity. You could simply dispatch the deferreds in a daisy chain, like you suggested, running the next one in the success callback of the previous one, respectively.

Comment: Yeah, I think I've to go with daisy chain in this case. Thanks.